# Translate Handlebars block helpers using end tags into Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

In Meteor, I have an app where I make a list of items grouped by tags, where non-tagged items come first and then tagged items are hidden under a "tag header" drop down.

I haven't touched this app since 0.8 came out, and I was using a block helper in a template which worked fine in pre-0.8...

[See working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/platypus117/1ey66hum/)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachItem', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";

  for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
      if(!context[i].tag){
         ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);
      } else {
          if(i===0||!context[i-1].tag ||context[i-1].tag !== context[i].tag){

             ret = ret + '<li class="list-group-item"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#'+ context[i].tag +'"> Items tagged  '+context[i].tag + '</a></li><div id="'+context[i].tag+'" class="collapse">';
          }
          ret = ret + options.fn(context[i]);

          if(i+1<j && context[i+1].tag !== context[i].tag){
              ret = ret + '</div>';
          }
      }
  }
  return ret;
});
```

But I'm struggling a bit to [translate this into post-0.8 Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/556c0e28e94b9351cbf0b28e80a71a4e35f1362a/packages/spacebars/README.md)

```
The inserted HTML must consist of balanced HTML tags. You can't, for example, 
insert "    </div><div>" to close an existing div and open a new one.
```

One idea I had was to render the non-tagged items and also the containers in a vanilla {{#each}} loop (with 2 different templates), and then do something like this

```
Template.myListContainer.rendered = function(){
    _.each(tags, function(tag){
        var tagged_items = _.filter(items, function(item){ return item.tag == tag; });
        _.each(tagged_items, function(item){
            UI.insert(UI.RenderWithData(listItemTemplate, { item : item }), tagContainer);
        });
    });
}
```

Is there a simpler way to do this ? If the items come from a collection, will they keep their reactivity ? 
Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, it's worth reading the [Meteor wiki on migrating to blaze.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze)

Anyhow, this one seems difficult to implement as a straight iteration.

If you *don't* need them in a specific order, I would just list items w/ and w/o tags, eg:

```
Template.example.helpers({
  dataWithoutTags: function(){
    return items.find({tag:{exists: false}});
  },
  tagList: function(){
    // create a distinct list of tags
    return  _.uniq(items.find({tag:{exists: true}}, {tag: true}));
  },
  dataForTag: function(){
    // use `valueOf` as `this` is a boxed-string
    return items.find({tag: this.valueOf()});
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="example">
  <div class='panel panel-default'>
  <ul class='list-group'>
      {{#each dataWithoutTags}}
        <li class='list-group-item'>{{name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
      {{#each tagList}}
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{this}}"> Items tagged  {{this}}</a>
        </li>
        <div id="{{this}}" class="collapse">
          {{#each dataForTag}}
              <li class='list-group-item'>{{name}}</li>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you *do* need them in a specific order - eg. *grouping only consecutive items* (as per your example). The only option would be to pre-process them.

eg:

```
Template.example.helpers({
  itemsGrouped: function(){
    dataGroups = [];
    currentGroup = null;
    items.find({}, {sort: {rank: 1}}).forEach(function(item){
      if (currentGroup && (!item.tag || currentGroup.tag != item.tag)){
          dataGroups.push(currentGroup);
          currentGroup = null;
      } 
       if (item.tag){
          if (!currentGroup){
            currentGroup = {
              group: true,
              tag: item.tag,
              items: [item]
            };
          } else {
            currentGroup.items.push(item);
          }
       } else {
          dataGroups.push(item);
       }
    });
    if (currentGroup){ dataGroups.push(currentGroup); }
    return dataGroups;
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<template name="example">
  <div class='panel panel-default'>
  <ul class='list-group'>
      {{#each itemsGrouped}}
        {{#if group}}
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{tag}}"> Items tagged  {{tag}}</a>
            </li>
            <div id="{{tag}}" class="collapse">
              {{#each items}}
                  <li class='list-group-item'>{{name}}</li>
              {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{else}}
          <li class='list-group-item'>{{name}}</li>
        {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: cheers nathan - yes this is pretty much the conclusion i've come to as well. a lot of advantages to Blaze's reactivity but just a few cases like mine fall through the cracks :/

Answer (score 0):

If you log the value you are returning from the `eachItem` helper, you will see you are not closing the last `div` element. Fixing that may get it working again. However, you have `div` elements as direct children of the `ul` element, which you are not supposed to [according to the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html):

> Permitted contents: Zero or more li elements

Also, I think it would be a better option for you to prepare your context in a format that makes it easier to let simple templates take care of the rendering. For example, using the same data from your jsfiddle, suppose you had it in the following format:

```
tagGroups = [{
  names: ["item1", "item2"]
},{
  tag: "red",
  names: ["item3", "item4"]
},{
  tag: "blue",
  names: ["item5", "item6", "item7"]
}]
```

The following templates would give you the expected result in a valid html format. The ending result is a bootstrap panel containing collapsible list-groups:

```
<template name="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    {{#each tagGroups}}
      {{> tagGroup}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="tagGroup">
  {{#if tag}}
    {{> namesListCollapse}}
  {{else}}
    {{> namesList}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="namesList">
  <ul class="list-group">
    {{#each names}}
      <li class="list-group-item">{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="namesListCollapse">
  <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{tag}}">Items tagged {{tag}}</a></div>
  <ul id="{{tag}}" class="panel-collapse collapse list-group">
    {{#each names}}
      <li class="list-group-item">
        {{this}}
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

And here is an example of a helper to transform your data so you can make a quick test to see it working:

```
Template.accordion.tagGroups = function () {

    var data =  [{
      name : 'item1'
    },{
      name : 'item2'
    },{
      name : 'item3',
      tag : 'red'
    },{
      name : 'item4',
      tag : 'red'
    },{
      name : 'item5',
      tag : 'blue'
    },{
      name : 'item6',
      tag : 'blue'
    },{
      name : 'item7',
      tag : 'blue'
    }];

    data = _.groupBy(data, 'tag');

    data = _.map(data, function (value, key) {
      var obj = {};

      if (key !== 'undefined') {
        obj.tag = key;
      }

      var names = _.map(value, function (item) {
        return item.name;
      });
      obj.names = names;

      return obj;
    });

    //console.dir(data);
    return data;
  };
```

And yes, if the items come from a collection, you will get reactivity by default.